# How to reference OpenAPI Generator task properties

Tags: swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I am attempting to reference assigned property generatorName when setting outputDir.

Attempted to reference generatorName property using same syntax as other task properties (i.e. $buildDir). Also attempted to more fully qualify the property name openApiGenerator.generatorName.

```
openApiGenerate {
    verbose = false
    generatorName = "html2"   // assignment to property
    inputSpec = "$buildDir/swagger/testing.yml".toString()
    //outputDir = "$buildDir/generated".toString()
    outputDir = "$buildDir/generated/$generatorName".toString() // fails
    apiPackage = "org.openapi.example.api"
    invokerPackage = "org.openapi.example.invoker"
    modelPackage = "org.openapi.example.model"

    // debugging code
    println "  buildDir:      $buildDir".toString()
    println "  generatorName: $generatorName".toString()  // this fails
}
```

output from debugging code shows failure to reference generatorName property:

```
> Configure project :
  buildDir:      C:\Users\jgunchy\repos\testingproject\build
  generatorName: property(class java.lang.String, fixed(class java.lang.String, html2))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an observable property, not a string. You should be able to access the underlying string using `.get()` like this:

```
openApiGenerate {
    verbose = false
    generatorName = "html2"
    inputSpec = "$buildDir/swagger/testing.yml".toString()
    outputDir = "$buildDir/generated/${generatorName.get()}".toString()
    apiPackage = "org.openapi.example.api"
    invokerPackage = "org.openapi.example.invoker"
    modelPackage = "org.openapi.example.model"
}
```

Another option would be to use configuration rather than the project extension container's properties directly. For instance, add to `gradle.properties`:

```
generatorName=html2
```

Then, your configuration would look like this:

```
openApiGenerate {
    verbose = false
    generatorName = project.ext.generatorName
    inputSpec = "$buildDir/swagger/testing.yml".toString()
    outputDir = "$buildDir/${project.ext.generatorName}".toString()
    apiPackage = "org.openapi.example.api"
    invokerPackage = "org.openapi.example.invoker"
    modelPackage = "org.openapi.example.model"
}
```

`$buildDir` is a getter on the Project instance with a `toString()` method that happens to output the File path, which is why it behaves differently.